# MySQL keeps getting same error "Packets out of order"

Tags: mysql, ruby, runtime-error

I have read through the similar questions and nothing seems to fix my issue. The exact error I get is:

```
/mysql.rb:1019:in `read': Packets out of order: 0<>  (RuntimeError)

from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mysql.rb:444:in `read'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mysql.rb:110:in `real_connect'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mysql.rb:91:in `initialize'
from testmysql.rb:6:in `new'
from testmysql.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

My code is just a test script to check out how to use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'mysql'

begin
con = Mysql.new 'localhost', 'username', 'password'
puts con.get_server_info
rs = con.query 'SELECT VERSION()'
puts rs.fetch_row

rescue Mysql::Error=> e
puts e.errno
puts e.error

ensure
con.close if con
end
```

I know there has to be something I have overlooked.

Comment: Instead of `mysql` try the `mysql2` adapter.  `gem install mysql2`.

Comment: ... and of course `require 'mysql2'`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Seem like a Bug `http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12490`